# vim pressing Esc key causing previous text to be pasted in insert mode

Tags: vim

I am trying to figure out what is happening when I press Esc. What I notice is that, if I am in Insert mode Esc will paste the previously entered text. I am using vim 7.2 on a rhel 6 linux server connected via iTerm2

This happens when I press Esc two or more times, pressing Esc once will correctly exit insert mode.

Comment: Does this still occur if you start Vim via `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: @NikitaKouevda It does happen. If I have typed something, then Esc Esc is repeating it.

Comment: Perhaps you have some key code that starts with Esc.  Does it happen if you type Esc, wait two seconds, then type Esc again?  If so, then try `:set timeoutlen=100` (1/10 second) or lower.

Comment: Strange thing is that it does not happen always. I am trying to reproduce it to try out your suggestions. Thanks.